# C#: char array reverse with 2 method, one methode with direct length. one method with value. Why the second Method doen'nt work?

Tags: c#, arrays, char, reverse

i create two methods to reverse char Array, when i give length to a temp Char array, and then do reverse, it works(methode: reversChar:  "char[] tempChar = new Char[testChar.Length];"), but when i give value to the temp char array, and then do reverse, it does not work(methode: reversCharVersion2: "char[] tempChar = testChar;"). Could anyone look at the problem and help me to find the reason, many thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        public char[] reversChar(char[] testChar)
        {

            char[] tempChar = new Char[testChar.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < testChar.Length; i++)
            {
                tempChar[i] = testChar[(testChar.Length - 1) - i];
            }
            return tempChar;
        }

        public char[] reversCharVersion2(char[] testChar)
        {
            char[] tempChar = testChar;
            for (int i = 0; i < testChar.Length; i++)
            {
                tempChar[i] = testChar[(testChar.Length - 1) - i];
            }
            return tempChar;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Vorbereitung Test Data
            Test myTest = new Test();
            char[] testChar = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
            char[] outputChar;

            //Methode 1 funktioniert
            outputChar = myTest.reversChar(testChar);
            Console.WriteLine(outputChar);

            //Methode 2 funktioniert nicht
            outputChar = myTest.reversCharVersion2(testChar);
            Console.WriteLine(outputChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are references. When you assign one array variable to another array variable, you do not make a copy, but both variables point to the same array. Since your algorithm only goes over the array from one direction, it will overwrite the other half of the array before reaching it. You have to change your algorithm that instead of copying one character inside the loop, only loop over half of the array, but exchange the characters in both directions.

Comment: Your two variables are referring to the same array in the second example

Comment: Thank you for all your Explanation, i changed my algorithm und do both sides. and now i understand a single variable is diffrent with a group variable. with a group of variable, like Array, class name, its all references.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not reversal. It just copies the original char array to a new array in reverse order.

But in second case, you are using the same array, they values are getting replaced on 
 the same reference place. The output you are getting in second case is 54345
You need to use following code in second case

```
public char[] reversCharVersion2(char[] testChar)
{
     char[] tempChar = testChar;
     char temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < (testChar.Length/2); i++)
     {
         temp = tempChar[i];
         tempChar[i] = testChar[(testChar.Length - 1) - i];
         testChar[(testChar.Length - 1) - i] = temp;
     }
     return tempChar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, its very helpful, my problem has been solved.